# PHP - link array of key / value pairs as key => value?

Tags: php, arrays

First I got some simple key / value pairs:

```
$a1['a'] = array(value1, value2);
$a1['b'] = array(value1, value2);
# ...
```

Now I want to use a1 as a key to other values, is that possible?

```
DoSomething($a1 => value);
```

I want to make a small search script for MySQL, my classes are almost finished. I thought to do this:

```
$fieldsWhereToSearch['tableWhereToSearch'] = array('bla', 'blabla');
$mySearchObject->search($fieldsWhereToSearch[tableWhereToSearch] => searchTerm);
```

My class would pick the matching sql, add a WHERE string with all the fields LIKE term.

Comment: Explain more, is hard to understand what you want to achieve

Comment: Ok, I want to make a small search script for MySQL, my classes are almost finished. I thought to do this:
    $fieldsWhereToSearch['tableWhereToSearch'] = array('bla', 'blabla');
    $mySearchObject->search($fieldsWhereToSearch[tableWhereToSearch] => searchTerm);
My class would pick the matching sql, add a WHERE string with all the fields LIKE term

Comment: @user3341388: And why are you not simply using `,` instead of `=>`? Just pass two arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because in PHP [array](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) keys can only be strings and integers:

> The key can either be an integer or a string. The value can be of any
>   type.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly. As @Jon said, the key can only be an integer or a string.

It seems that you need to create a multidimensional array as you can use an array as an array value.

Please explain what you are trying to accomplish and perhaps we can help more...